# Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer : Requested value 'NotRegistered' was not found

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I am using below command in Azure Automation Powershell script to get status of Recovery Services container - it simply checks if a VM is registered for backup.

```
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $AzureRecoveryServicesName | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext
$BackupStatus = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM -FriendlyName $VirtualMachineName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
```

If a VM is not registered it throws an error and $BackupStatus is empty:

> Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer : Requested value 'NotRegistered' was not found.
>
> At line:53 char:21
>
> - ... kupStatus = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType ...
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmReco...BackupContainer], ArgumentException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>
> Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.GetAzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer

And if it is already registered I get $BackupStatus = Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.AzureVmContainer.
I've tried:

```
$BackupStatus = (Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM -FriendlyName $VirtualMachineName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName).Status
```

But then the only difference is that I get $BackupStatus = Registered when VM is already in a container but same error occurs when VM is not registered.

What is the proper way to check if a VM is registered for backup or not? I am ok with what I'm getting - I can handle $BackupStatus values in a script - but I don't want this error message to show.

Strange thing is that in Powershell on PC with same Azure modules versions loaded (AzureRM​.RecoveryServices​.Backup 2.5.0) as in Automation Account I am getting a different behavior:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $BackupStatus = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM -FriendlyName $VirtualMachineName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
PS C:\windows\system32> $BackupStatus

        Name                                     ResourceGroupName                        Status               ContainerType
        ----                                     -----------------                        ------               -------------
        UbuntuBckptest                           rhel68128                                Registered           AzureVM
```

It returns an object instead of a string.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set $BackupStatus value according to  `Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer` command executed result. We could put the `Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer` in `try...catch`.
The following just the  code sample

```
$BackupStatus;
try
{

$BackupStatus=Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer 

}
catch
{
  # we can add condition for example : if($BackupStatus.Contains("NotRegistered"))
   $BackupStatus = "NotRegistered"

}
# we can add condition :get the type of $BackupStatus for example :if($BackupStatus.GetType().Name.equals("String"))`
$BackupStatus = "Registered"
```